# Fetching data from JSON using json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar

Tags: java, json, getjson

I am trying to parse a simple json data using the json-lib jar. The JSON data
has below format:

```
{"plantDetails":
    [{
        "common":"New Plant 1",
            "botanical":"",
            "light":"Mostly Shady",
            "price":0,
            "availDate":"10/25/2012",
            "indoor":false,
            "id":null
    },{
        "common":"New Plant 1",
            "botanical":"",
            "light":"Mostly Shady",
            "price":0,
            "availDate":"10/25/2012",
            "indoor":false,
            "id":null
    },{
        "common":"New Plant 1",
            "botanical":"",
            "light":"Mostly Shady",
            "price":0,
            "availDate":"10/25/2012",
            "indoor":false,
            "id":null
    }]
}
```

For this, I am using the below code:

```
try {
    net.sf.json.JSONObject jsonObject = net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(jb.toString());               
    JSONArray arr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("plantDetails");
    //net.sf.json.JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("plantDetails");
    Iterator iter = arr.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) iter.next();
        System.out.println(object.getString("common"));
        System.out.println(object.getString("botanical"));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // crash and burn
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code works fine when there are more than one JSONObject (i.e. 3 in my
case). But unfortunately, it does not work when the number of JSON Object is
only 1. It is throwing an exception: `net.sf.json.JSONException:
JSONObject["plantDetails"] is not a JSONArray.`

How to give a check like if the there are more than one JSONObject present or
not?

One way to resolve this is to use this bit of code once the above exception is
thrown in the try/catch block for only one JSONObject and then fetch the
corresponding values:

```
net.sf.json.JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("plantDetails");
```

But I don't want to go this way:

1) There might be some better way to achieve the same rather than catching an exception and handling it to fetch an Object value

2) Need to know the best way of achieveing the same

Please let me know about this.

Regards,

Comment: try google json parser GSon. I'm parse similar data without problems

Comment: What does the JSON string look like with only one object?

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but I cant to use gon as of now in this project and have to accomplish this using the json-lib jar only.

Comment: For one object it will be like this: `{"plantDetails":
[{
    "common":"New Plant 1",
    "botanical":"",
    "light":"Mostly Shady",
    "price":0,
    "availDate":"10/25/2012",
    "indoor":false,
    "id":null
}]}`

Comment: @user182944 - this makes no sense, if this is the string you get for one object, then it is also an array that contains one object, it should not fail. On what line exactly are you failing (in the code snippet you provided)?

Comment: I completely agree with you, this is what I also thought the very 1st time when saw that exception. It is failing in this line: `JSONArray arr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("plantDetails");`